# Formating List Problems in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a few lines of code on every Server (160+).
For this I decided to get my Serverlist via Powercli and pass this list to `Enter-PSSession`.

```
...
Connect-VIServer -Server $VIServer -Credential $creds
$servers = Get-VM |select Name |where Name -Like "SV*"
...

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    try{
        Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
            Get-NetIPAddress |where AddressFamily -EQ 2 |where InterfaceAlias -Like "Ethernet" |select IPAddress
        Exit-PSSession
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Error on $server"
    }
}
```

the problem seems to be, that it takes an array as the ouput error is following

`Error on @{Name=<$server>}`

But I dont know how to handle this correctly

Comment: Don't use `enter-pssession` in a script! Use `invoke-command` instead

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I need to connect for the server for another part of the code but thank you for the input i forgot about the "execution level"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `New-Pssession` or `Invoke-command` for remoting. `Enter-Pssession` is interactive and the way you are doing it, the `get-netipaddress` is running on your local machine and not on your remote machine.

Use `$servers.Name` instead of `$servers` in your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($server in $servers.Name) #This .name should fix your problem
{
    try{
        New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -Name MySession
        Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock {Get-NetIPAddress |where AddressFamily -EQ 2 |where InterfaceAlias -Like "Ethernet" |select IPAddress}
        Remove-PSSession
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Error on $server"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick help and the clear answer. After you mentiond the .Name i was thinking how dumb someone can be from time to time. And thank you for the help with the remote-automation